# Why is it both "Mai" and "My" used for the title?

Tags: mai-hime

When we look at the title for *Mai-HiME* and *Mai-Otome* it's written in 2 ways

- Mai-HiME/Otome
- My-HiME/Otome

We can see this in [Manga Updates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=114), [My Anime List](https://myanimelist.net/anime/98/Mai-HiME), [Anime Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/my-hime) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My-HiME) where either they list the alternate names showing both Mai and My to making a choice between My or Mai.

When we look at the list of Associated names on Manga Updates it shows

- 舞-HiME
- Dancing Princess
- Mai HiME
- My HiME
- My Princess
- My-HiME
- Princess Mai

considering that one of the characters (the main one in Mai-HiME) is Tokiha Mai and the Japanese used for the title is 舞-HiME with [google translate](https://translate.google.com.au/#ja/en/%E8%88%9E) showing 舞 is pronounced as "mai" which it translates to "dance", the associated names have different 3 different meanings

- Possession of a Princess/Hime
- Referring to Mai as a Princess/Hime
- matching the google translation of 舞 (mai)

I am wondering why does sites associate "My" and "Mai" for the title? to me it seems both "My" and "Mai" give the title different meanings

Comment: Just FYI, Mai's name is 舞衣, not 舞.

Comment: @AkiTanaka is that just the Mai part of her name? or could the second part be Tokiha? (i don't recall seeing Mai's name written in japanese)

Comment: I should have been clearer... but yes, her name is 鴇羽 舞衣 (Tokiha Mai). This is according to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%88%9E-HiME%E3%81%AE%E7%99%BB%E5%A0%B4%E4%BA%BA%E7%89%A9#%E9%B4%87%E7%BE%BD%E8%88%9E%E8%A1%A3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any official word on why both romanizations are used. However, Funimation's official name for the show is [My-Hime](https://www.funimation.com/shows/my-hime/), while the technical romanization of 舞 is mai. As such, it seems as though sites use Mai-Hime because that is the technically correct romanization of "舞 Hime" and use My-Hime because that's the title that companies such as Funimation and Bandai use for the show (just as how Attack on Titan is also listed as Shingeki no Kyojin).

EDIT: to add/expand on what Aki Tanaka mentioned from [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%88%9E-HiME#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81), it seems the name is also a pun, where because it's about moe characters, the creator wanted people to "please find (My) princess (HiME) for oneself" (approximate translation, because my Japanese is rusty and direct translations are hard). [HiME](http://mai-otome-hime.wikia.com/wiki/Mai-HiME_terminology) is also a backronym for Highly-advanced Materializing Equipment, which is the ability that the main characters have.

Comment: Perhaps it's really a pun. [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%88%9E-HiME#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81) mentioned the reason behind the title that "「自分自身にとっての (My) お姫様 (HiME) を見つけて下さい」という制作者の主張が込められている（北米でのタイトルが "My-HiME" であることからも分かる）"